# Count and join many to many relationship with SQLAlchemy

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using Flask SQLAlchemy and have the following model:

```
subscribers = db.Table('subscribers',
    db.Column('subscriber_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('followed_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
)

class Base(db.Model):
__abstract__  = True
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class User(Base):
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True)
    subscribes = db.relationship('User', 
        secondary=subscribers, 
        primaryjoin="User.id==subscribers.c.subscriber_id",
        secondaryjoin="User.id==subscribers.c.followed_id",
        backref=db.backref('followers', lazy='dynamic'), 
        lazy='dynamic')
```

What I'm trying to do is to write a query that gets the user's email, name and amount of followers.

This is the result I get when I try a raw SQL query:

```
print >> sys.stderr, db.session.execute('SELECT u.*, fol_count.followers_count FROM User AS u LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT followed_id, count(*) AS followers_count FROM subscribers GROUP BY followed_id) AS fol_count ON fol_count.followed_id = u.id')
# # ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) column u.id does not exist
# # [1] LINE 1: ...BY followed_id) AS fol_count ON fol_count.followed_id = u.id
```

I also tried without naming User as u and wrote users.* and users.id instead. users.* at the start of the query did not raise any errors, but users.id at the end gave me an error saying that users had a missing FROM clause. Writing User instead of users didn't work either.

This one is free from errors, but it doesn't include followers_count in the result object:

```
subquery = db.session.query(subscribers, func.count('*').label('followers_count')).group_by('followed_id', 'subscriber_id').subquery() 
user = User.query.outerjoin(subquery, User.id == subquery.c.followed_id).first()
```

I have even printed this line, but it always returns 0, even though it is supposed to return 1 in my test case.

```
print >> sys.stderr, db.session.query(User).join(subscribers, User.id == subscribers.c.followed_id).count()
```

I do have other subscription related code that works, so I don't understand why I can't get the followers amount code to work or why it returns 0. Anyone who sees any mistakes I've done?

Comment: `db.session.query(User).join(subscribers, User.id == subscribers.c.followed_id).count()` returning 0 would hint that there are no subscriptions, at all. Are you connecting to the correct DB?

Comment: I fixed that problem, just a miss in some other code. It now returns 1, but the user-query does still not include followers_count.